# How to copy from csv file date in format yyyymmdd into a column with datatype date?

Tags: postgresql, csv, date, copy

I want to import a large csv file into a postgres DB. The csv file ist zipped. The dateformat in the csv file is yyyymmdd. Is it possible to import in the table with datatype date ?

```
CREATE TABLE "t_test" (
            "MyDate" date );
        
copy  "t_test" ("MyDate") 
FROM PROGRAM 
    'unzip -p C:\tmp\Mydate_testfile.zip' 
WITH DELIMITER AS ';' NULL as 'null' CSV header;
```

Comment: Easy enough to  test: `select '20230815'::date; 2023-08-15`.

Comment: Sure.  What happened when you made the attempt you showed us?

Comment: in that case ist the column saved as text and by each quer i must use to declare it as date. it works...but is there a solution to handle it by import in the same way ?